# How to remove index.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, iis, codeigniter

How to remove index.php in codeigniter on Windows 7 and IIS.

I searched net for the solution but result weree based on re-write module of Apache, if anyone has worked on IIS and Windows 7 and had similar situation pls help on this.

I want to work on IIS and Windows 7 and if I can remove index.php while calling any particular controller / module.

Comment: If this is a production box then i wouldnt keep it on windows too long. Windows + PHP is still shaky at best and has a lot of problems. Best to move to a linux box for production. if this is just for development you should be fine but you may want to look into XAMPP
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) for that if you are under IIS.

Comment: @Viral once you've got that working make sure you set `$config['index_page']` to a blank string as well!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [IIRF (Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter)](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx) which is a rewriter for IIS that unlike ISAPI_Rewrite is completely free for the full functionality.  The lite version of ISAPI_Rewrite might suffice for just this one issue (removing index.php for CodeIgniter), but IIRF can do so much more.